# Is it possible to sort a dict by datetime value, "exceptions.TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to unicode"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dict that I want to sort by the value of key 'entry_date' which is a datetime value.
Most of the examples of sorting a dict are focused on numerical keys rather than string keys, and
also primitive values rather than complex object values.

I'd appreciate some help in adapting the sort for my particular problem.

```
data = {"entry_date": datetime.now(), "thisdata": "foo", "thatdata": "bar"}  # The code is 2.7
print(sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]))

exceptions.TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to unicode
```

My guess is that I need to convert the entry_date value to a string? But:

```
print(sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x: x[1].strptime(dateFormat)))
```

is clearly not going to work. Some values in the dict are primitives.
Perhaps I am expecting Python to do work that I need to be doing?

Comment: I think there is a typo, ```print(sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x: x[0]))```

Comment: 0 would sort it on the first item, which is the key. I'm replacing key with value, per the example I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the datetime object to its default string representation if you want to compare it with other string types as mentioned in your example. Or if you want the datetime object to have different format in string representation then you can try `strftime` method https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

Following is how the default string representation for a datetime objects looks:

```
>>> d = datetime.now()
>>> str(d)
'2020-07-18 00:40:51.139134'
```

So in your case it will be:

```
data = {"entry_date": datetime.now(), "thisdata": "foo", "thatdata": "bar"}
print(sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x: str(x[1])))
```